# LengthFieldBasedFrameDecoder not calling next handler

Tags: netty

I'm using a `LengthFieldBasedFrameDecoder` as my first handler for inbound traffic which is send from a client.

Length: 4 bytes
Payload: Hello - 5 bytes

`[0, 0, 0, 9, 72, 101, 108, 108, 111]`

```
ServerBootstrap b = new ServerBootstrap();
b.group(bossGroup, workerGroup)
    .channel(NioServerSocketChannel.class)
    .childHandler(new ChannelInitializer<SocketChannel>() {
        @Override
        public void initChannel(SocketChannel ch) throws Exception {
            ch.pipeline().addLast("frameDecoder", new PacketFrameDecoder());
            ch.pipeline().addLast(new GameServerHandler());
        }
    })
    .option(ChannelOption.SO_BACKLOG, 128)
    .childOption(ChannelOption.SO_KEEPALIVE, true);

// Bind and start to accept incoming connections.
ChannelFuture f = b.bind(port).sync();
```

In `ByteToMessageDecoder` I see `fireChannelRead(ctx, out, size)` being called with an empty out and size 0. No exception seem to be thrown. I've tried both endianness in the decoder.

```
public class PacketFrameDecoder extends LengthFieldBasedFrameDecoder {

    //Constants
    private static final int MAX_FRAME_LENGTH = Integer.MAX_VALUE;
    private static final int LENGTH_FIELD_OFFSET = 0;
    private static final int LENGTH_FIELD_LENGTH = 4;
    private static final int LENGTH_FIELD_ADJUSTMENT = 0;
    private static final int INITIAL_BYTES_TO_STRIP = 4;

    //Constructors
    public PacketFrameDecoder() {
        super(MAX_FRAME_LENGTH, LENGTH_FIELD_OFFSET, LENGTH_FIELD_LENGTH,
            LENGTH_FIELD_ADJUSTMENT, INITIAL_BYTES_TO_STRIP);

    }

}
```

After that, I want to handle my body/payload in the `GameServerHandler` which extends `ChannelInboundHandlerAdapter`.

```
public class GameServerHandler extends ChannelInboundHandlerAdapter {

    /**
     * This method is called with the received message, whenever new data is received from a client.
     * @param context
     * @param message
     */
    @Override
    public void channelRead(ChannelHandlerContext context, Object message) {
        Log.i("GameServerHandler"); //Breakpoint here
        ByteBuf in = (ByteBuf) message;
        try {
            String test = in.toString(io.netty.util.CharsetUtil.US_ASCII);
            Log.i(test);
        } finally {
            ReferenceCountUtil.release(message);
        }
    }

    @Override
    public void exceptionCaught(ChannelHandlerContext context, Throwable cause) {
        // Close the connection when an exception is raised.
        cause.printStackTrace();
        context.close();
    }

}
```

But the `channelRead` in my `GameServerHandler` is not called or fired. I have no idea what I'm doing wrong.

Answer (score 1):

I just found out that the problem seems to be related to the length adjustment.
My headers (4 bytes) are incorporated in the total length so there are 2 options:

1. Subtract the header length from the Length Field Adjustment:  `LENGTH_FIELD_ADJUSTMENT = -4`
2. Don't encapsulate the header length when sending the message and only contain the payload